# how to separate separate function(tab) in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have got my Mainwindow class , Mainwindow.xaml and Mainwindow.cs. Problem is I have got 4 tabs and each tab has own functions. All this is on my Mainwindow.xaml and cs. Is there any way of separating them because my Mainwindow.Xaml is getting bigger and bigger and then I get confuse with so much code.Probably is bit basic what I am asking but I dont know how to do separate with xaml, becasue I want to keep the layout as it is.

Hope I have explained well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different `UserControls` for each tab. And each tab has the corresponding `UserControl` like this:

`<myControls:userProfileTabControl />`

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/UserControl.aspx) is some more documentation on how to create and use a `UserControl` in WPF. There is also a video over att WindowsClient that talks about ["How to Create a User Control in WPF"](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=76360).

When you feel comfortable with the basis of WPF you might want to consider looking into the MVVM pattern, you can [read about it over at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), there are frameworks to use to make MVVM easier such as PRISM. But often they tend to do things a bit more complicated.

Start off by seperating your tabs into different User Controls and go from there.

Comment: @ Filip thak a lot for your answer and links I ll have a look

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small application, you can create a User control for each tab's content, and then implement all the logic there. You then embed your user controls in each tab.

If the application can grow, or you want to put a bit more of order in there, take a look to [The PRISM Framework](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @ Haplo Tks a lot for your reply I ll have a look on what you said.